# SQL data processing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an MS SQL database where sensor data is being streamed from a low level device, into say column 1.

In columns 2 and 3 I have some alarm levels.

What I would like to do is for "some script" to test the data as it arrives in column 1 against the levels in columns 2 and 3 and place a boolean decision in column 4.

My question is can I have some SQL script to do this? Where would it reside or does my low level device need knowledge of the column 2 and 3 trip points and when it posts the data to column 1 it also posts the decision to column 4?

UPDATE - First Test

I have implemented this and tested in sqlfiddle (but I am unable to login for some reason) so here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE SensorData(
  data1 float NULL,
  data1alarm bool NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);  
//
CREATE TABLE SensorConfig(
  data1max float NULL,
  data1min float NULL
);  
//
CREATE TRIGGER Alarm
AFTER INSERT 
ON SensorData FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (new.data1 > 5.0) AND (new.data1 < 60.0) THEN
    INSERT INTO SensorData(data1alarm) 
    VALUES(true);
  END IF;
END
//
INSERT INTO SensorConfig(data1max, data1min) VALUES (200.0, 100.0);
INSERT INTO SensorData(data1) VALUES (10.0);
```

When `INSERT INTO SensorData(data1) VALUES (10.0);` I get the error:

`Can't update table 'sensordata' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

but when `INSERT INTO SensorData(data1) VALUES (1.0);` then the schema builds.

I cannot figure out the problem.

Also, I want really to implement such a condition that a true is written when `data1` is greater `data1max` and less than `data1min`.

But at the moment I not sure why the schema does not build?

Furthermore, when I have tried getting the data1min and data1max into the conditional part of the trigger I have encountered errors:

`IF (new.data1 > SensorConfig.data1min) AND (new.data1 < SensorConfig.data1max) THEN`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to store this data? Why not have column4 calculated dynamically in a view?

Comment: I do not want to display all the data, only that outside the bounds ... could I query each line and test column 1 against columns 2 and 3 as an SQL query?

Comment: Sure, see my answer below

Comment: I suspect that the error comes because the trigger is based on SensorData attempts to update SensorData. That is - the trigger is not allowed to manipulate the table that triggered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you don't insert things into your table, but rather create a view that contains the logic for the alarm codes. So you might do

```
create view alarming_data as
select 
    data1.thevalue as theValue
    true as theAlarm
from
    data1 where data1.theValue > 5 and data1.theValue < 60
```

That keeps your raw data "pure" and your processing separate. In fact, you don't really need the second field, I'm just putting it there to keep my answer as close to your example as possible.

You can query this view as you would a table, and if your definition of alarming changes, it's just a matter of updating the definition of the view.

Comment: I appreciate that alternative way of thinking about my problem. Just to share a little more about my application. I periodically query the DB and display the data values on a graph. If I detect an alarm then I need to inform some user. My thinking behind setting boolean for the alarm trip levels are globals and so could be have a different value when looking back over historic data, but at least you would know from the boolean column whether an alarm was detected, rather than re-runninng the logic - so it is more than just viewing the data.

Comment: I guess only you know the ins and outs of how your application works. If you're a programmer by background and coming to databases from that perspective, I think the best advice I can give you is that a view is a building block of abstraction in databases in much the same way that a function is procedurally. Keeping a column in a table and updating it with triggers is, in my experience, significant;y more error prone than using views, but there are plenty of trade-offs to make in each direction.

Comment: Using "Views" is a neat solution which I had not considered.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display the offending lines, you don't need to persist `column4`, you can query them dynamically:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  column1 > column2 OR column1 > column3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a trigger for that table with option AFTER INSERT

```
CREATE TRIGGER trDoMagic
ON YourTable
AFTER INSERT
   your magic code
```

Comment: First of all we have to understand which kind of SQL you are using, since I don't recognize the syntax. Another thing to consider is that it is not clear to me if sensorconfig may have morethan 1 record or not: in the latter case which is the one we have to check against? Last but not least I've never tried to update an entry on a table using the insert trigger, but i would pretty sure you cannot insert new row from the insert trigger: you would risk an infinite loop! On Monday perhaps i will be able to add compete info